# Upgrading PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.0 for Zephir Parser (Unable to initialize module)

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension, php-8, zephir

`php -v` yields the following output:

```
PHP 8.0.28 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:32:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.28, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

`ls -l /etc/alternatives/*php*` yields the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/php-config -> /usr/bin/php-config8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/php-config.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php-config8.0.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/php.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php8.0.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/phpize -> /usr/bin/phpize8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Apr 17 20:51 /etc/alternatives/phpize.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/phpize8.0.1.gz
```

Following the documentation on Github, I run the following:

```
/etc/alternatives/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/etc/alternatives/php-config
make
make install
```

This creates the SO in the `./modules` directory and places it into the `/usr/lib/php/20200930` directory.

I then `vim /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini` and add `extension=zephir_parser.so` before saving and closing.

Running `php -v` now gives me:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zephir_parser: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.28 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:32:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.28, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I have PHP 7.4 installed on the target machine but its not picking up the PHP 8 config? Any help appreciated.

Update: Truncated output of the `make install`:

```
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/zephir_parser.so /home/someuser/zephir

/php-zephir-parser/modules/zephir_parser.so
libtool: install: cp ./.libs/zephir_parser.lai /home/someuser/zephir/php-zephir-parser/modules/zephir_parser.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.7.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /home/someuser/zephir/php-zephir-parser/modules
[...]
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/20200930/
Installing header files:          /usr/include/php/20200930/
```

Even putting the absolute path to the SO throws the same build version error:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/zephir_parser.so
```

`php -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zephir_parser: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20200930
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.28 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:32:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.28, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Can you try `make distclean`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension/issues/76#issuecomment-469200811)?

Comment: @Olivier if you want to go ahead and create that as an answer, it worked beautifully! Just for clarification, I ran `make distclean` and then the following: `/etc/alternatives/phpize`, `./configure --with-php-config=/etc/alternatives/php-config` and `make && make install` as `sudo`. Thankyou ever so much, I was hung on this for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete old intermediate files remaining from the previous build, run the command:

`make distclean`

Then you can call `phpize`, `configure` and so on.